# VBA for determining chart type by number of rows in table

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to write some VBA that will automatically produce a certain type of chart based on the number of rows in a table. I'm using an IF loop, as below, based on a lastrow variable. i have scrolled through the code using F8 and the lastrow variable is registering correctly but this doesn't impact on the type of chart appearing - it is always a column chart, which i guess is the default setting... Any help greatly appreciated.

Segment of code:

```
With Worksheets("TableScores")
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
            If lastrow <= 3 Then
            .ChartType = xlBar
            Else:
            .ChartType = xlLine
            End If
End with
```

Comment: Does this code not raise an error? You're attempting to set `Worksheets("TableScores").ChartType = xlLine`.  This should raise a `438` error: Object does not support this property or method.  I'm guessing you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere, which is masking the error, and yielding the unexpected results.

Comment: `Selection.ChartType` should work, but I'd encourage you to use Tim's answer below, it is best not to rely on `Select` or `Activate` methods in VBA.

Answer (score 4):

(Untested)

```
With Worksheets("TableScores")
Dim cht as Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart()

    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrow <= 3 Then
        cht.ChartType = xlBar
    Else
        cht.ChartType = xlLine
    End If
End with
```

Comment: + 1 you beat me again!

Comment: @SiddharthRout - and I've not had my coffee yet!